# Framework7 on ajax success navigating to another page is not working

Tags: ajax, phonegap, html-framework-7

So i'm using phonegap/framework7 for an app i'm working on

i have the following ajax call which works just fine..

```
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: myApi+ "ratings",
        data: ratingForm,
        success: function() {

            //works fine
            alert("test success");

            //this part doesn't work!
            app.router.navigate("/success/");

        },
        error: function () {
            app.dialog.alert('We apologize, an error 
occurred while trying to saving your rating.  Please try 
again.');
        }
});
```

The part not working is the app.router.navigate("/success/"); part.  I have no errors in the console.  This function DOES work if called from anywhere else in the program, so i'm not sure how to handle redirecting after an ajax success, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know Framework7, but you mentioned that it works if you call it outside of that function, so have you tried calling a dedicated function that calls app.router.navigate('/success/').

Comment: yes i did, still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

i think you were supposed to use:

```
app.mainView.router.navigate('/success');
```

The missing part is the **mainView**

Comment: thank you, after lots of playing i finally got it to work, while i figured it out on my own you are not wrong at all, for me it was composeView.router.navigate("/success/");

Answer (score 0):

after lots of playing eventually, I got it working...
I'm using a tabbed layout, I have the following in app.js

var composeView = app.views.create('#view-compose', {
  url: '/compose/'
});

and on my ajax success i'm now doing...

composeView.router.navigate("/success/");

and it's routing properly, thank you to everyone who helped!